# Proving almost uniform convergence of $ n\sin(\frac{x}{n}) $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I'm learning about uniform convergence. For example, consider a function sequence

$$f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  f_n(x) =  n\sin(\frac{x}{n})$$

This sequence converges pointwise to $ f(x) = x $, but on $ \mathbb{R} $ the convergence is not uniform (one can look at $ f(\frac{\pi}{2n}) = n$ ).

I'm supposed to prove that on any closed interval $ [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $ the convergence is uniform.

To prove that I need to show that the supremum of

$$ | x - n\sin(\frac{x}{n}) | $$

converges to $ 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty $.

My take is this: if $ x \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $, then by Weierstrass theorem a continuous function on closed interval attains its maximum value, so there exists $ x_1 \in [a,b] $ that for every $x$

$$ | x - n\sin(\frac{x}{n}) | \leq | x_1 - n\sin(\frac{x_1}{n}) |$$

and then it's easy to see that as $n \rightarrow \infty $ the RHS also converges to $0$. But RHS is the supremum which converges to $0$, so the convergence is uniform on any $ [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $.

Is this method/trick correct? It seems like if it is, then proving almost uniform convergence can sometimes be easy just by invoking the Weierstrass theorem: suspiciously easy, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: The value of $x_1$ depends on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you *don't* have $f_n\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)=n$. You can prove that the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R$ usinge the fact that $f_n\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)=n$ for each natural $n$.

And your proof is wrong, since $x_1$ depends upon $n$.

I suggest that you define $g_n(x)=f_n(x)-x=n\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-x$ and then you prove that it converges uniformly to the null function on $[a,b]$. Use the fact that $g_n'(x)=\cos\left(\frac xn\right)-1$.